# Can I simulate C-style Macro in Perl?

Tags: perl

Code:

```
my $tmp='x $i y';  # define a macro or whatever

for my $i (0..5){
    my $var;
    #    eval { $var=$tmp; };       # A
    #    eval { $var="x $i y"; };   # B
    $var="x $i y";                  # C
    print $var."\n";
}
```

B and C would print

```
x 0 y
x 1 y
x 2 y
```

A print

```
x $i y
x $i y
x $i y
```

What's wrong in A?

Comment: Anything wrong with `sub not_macro { "x $_[0] y" }; print not_macro($_), "\n" for 0 .. 5;` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`eval BLOCK` only catches exceptions, so it's not relevant to the question. So that leaves us with the following code:

```
my $i;
my $tmp = 'x $i y';
$i = 3;
my $var = $tmp;
```

The right-hand side of the assignment is the same string in both cases, so why do you expect `$tmp` and `$var` to end up with different values? That makes no sense.

So how does one solve your problem? If you want the contents of `$tmp` to be used as a Perl code, you need to use `eval EXPR`, and the content of `$tmp` actually has to be Perl code.

```
my $i;
my $tmp = '"x $i y"';   # Quotes added to make it valid Perl.
$i = 3;
my $var = eval $tmp;    # eval EXPR instead of eval BLOCK.
```

But that's oh-so-wrong. You're using `eval EXPR` as template system. Use a real tempalte system, like [Template-Toolkit](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Template%3a%3aManual%3a%3aIntro). But if you want to keep using templates of the form `x $i y`, then look into [String::Interpolate](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?String%3a%3aInterpolate).

Answer (score 2):

If you eval `$tmp`, it will just return the string inside it, meaning you will do: `$var = 'x $i y'`. You need to eval the string in `$tmp`, but not `$var`. Also, you cannot directly eval the string, you need to enclose it in double quotes, to allow interpolation of `$i`, like so:

```
$tmp = '"x $i y"';  # note double quotes inside
...
$var = eval $tmp;
```

However, `eval` is rather a brutish solution to any such problem. Most of the times you think you need it, you need to think again. Your solution could be code references instead:

```
my $tmp = sub { my $num = shift; return "x $num y" };

for my $i (0 .. 5) {
    print $tmp->($i);
}
```

Here, you will not attempt to use the actual `$i` argument in the for loop, but instead pass `$i` as argument to the sub, who uses it and returns the string.

Answer (score 0):

Variable names in double-quoted strings are replaced with values, variables in single-quoted string are **not** (it's called [interpolation](http://perlmeme.org/howtos/using_perl/interpolation.html)). That's why the `A` options is printing `$i` instead of a value.

`A` does exactly the same as:

```
my $var = 'x $i y';
print $var."\n";     # prints 'x $i y\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

Well for starters, when you put a string in single quotes, it won't interpret your variables as being the values of them, but rather the literal string that you type.

Now as far as "making a macro", which is what you were trying to do. Here is a way to do it in perl, but honestly, code you write should never do this type of thing.

```
use strict;

# This is your "counter" variable
my $i = 0; 

# This is your "Macro"
my $macro = sub{ return 'x ' . ${\$i} . ' y'}; 

for my $x (0..5){

    $i = $x;
    print &{$macro}, "\n";

}
```

The result is:

```
x 0 y
x 1 y
x 2 y
x 3 y
x 4 y
x 5 y
```